# Possible to swipe down image to return previous screen?

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart

Is it possible to achieve this effect using flutter using hero animation and swipe down gesture listener/detector? Or is there any package that I can used that is already available?

Basically, when i swipe down an image in a stateless widget, it will go back to previous screen and return the image to its initial position just like the example shown below from reddit app.

I am using photo_view package for my image to allow user to pinch to zoom in. Not sure if there might be any gestures conflict.

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Apologies for the oversized gif image, i dont know how to make it smaller

[image: Example Reddit App]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the hero animation widget, just wrap the swipable area with `GestureDetector` like this:

```
GestureDetector(
 onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
   Navigator.pop(context);
 },
 child: ...
);
```

**Edit**

The [swipedetector](https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector) plugin that gives you more control of the drag setting, I didn't use it but it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. Problem is I am also using another package for the image to allow user to pinch to zoom. I'm not sure if there might be any conflict in the gestures. Package: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin, it adds some nice visual effects and no lags

https://pub.dev/packages/insta_image_viewer

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 140,
  child: InstaImageViewer(
    child: Image(
      image: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/id/507/1000").image,
    ),
  ),
),
```